# Parsing SQLite file columns without sqlite3.h header file

Tags: c, sqlite, parsing, low-level

I'm currently working on parsing a SQLite file for my **C** program, and I need to extract three columns, url, username, and password. **I want to parse it without using the sqlite3.h header file**. I could use some **pre-installed libraries on Windows**, but right now trying to make the parsing manual.

The passwords start all with a prefix "v10", so I can locate all the passwords, and then go back until I find "http" to get the url, but can't figure out how to parse the username from the middle.

Here is a example of a row:

> **http://example.com/index.php**http://example.com/index.phppostcode**343434**password**v10XXXXXXXXX**

In this case "v10XXXXXXXXX" is the password, and the username is "343434". How do I determine the length of the username?

Links to documentation about how they are formatted would be appreciated. I have tried reading the [SQLite Database File Format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html), but can't seem to understand. The idea is to make the file as small as possible, so can't use anything big.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds as if you basically want to implement part of the sqlite library, as in, duplicate some of its functionality. But if "I have tried reading the SQLite Database File Format, but can't seem to understand", then you'll have a hard time: that documentation should pretty much tell you how the database (and tables therein) are structured, so I would think you need that information to parse the data.

Comment: Can I ask what the specific reason is that you want to avoid using the sqlite C library for reading an sqlite database?

Comment: *"The idea is to make the file as small as possible, so can't use anything big."* What file? Database file? Header file?

Comment: @9769953 Yes indeed I should understand the documentation, but my situation is a bit different, since I know there is "v10" on each of the passwords and I know the url is the first proper string on the line, with sqlite.h I would just `SELECT * FROM 'x'`

Comment: @9769953 I don't really know. But I want to create the program with minimalistic includes.

Comment: @user694733 .exe I meant**

Comment: [SQLite features page](https://sqlite.org/features.html) says *"Small code footprint: less than 750KiB fully configured or much less with optional features omitted."*. Unless you are doing this for very memory constrained embedded device, I don't think it makes sense to try to avoid including the official header file. Even mobile phones from over 15 years ago included SQLite in their firmware.

Comment: Please clarify: is the source file a SQL script, or a binary database file?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Binary database.